# How do I send additional Exception data via CreateErrorResponse?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, owin

When programming in ASP.NET, and you wish to create HttpResponseMessage from an exception, you can use:

```
var httpResponseMessage =
  Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exception);
```

However, on the browser side, the "responseText" ends up receiving only the following properties of the Exception object: ExceptionMessage, ExceptionType, Message and StackTrace?

How can I send additional data?  If I create my own Exception class, or if I add the data to the Exception.Data object.

Comment: Are you asking yourself now?

Comment: Yes, T.S.  When you ask a question on StackOverflow, you are given the option to "Answer your own question".  It's encouraged.   Take a look here for their explanation: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing in the exception directly into CreateErrorResponse, pass in an HttpError object itself that you construct by passing in the exception.  Then you can add additional properties to the object that's returned to the client.

The code you have above is essentially the same as:

```
var httpError = new HttpError(exception, true);
var httpResponseMessage =
  Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, httpError);
```

You can call the Add method to httpError to additional fields.  For instance, if you want to add all of the key/values stored in the exception.Data property, your final code would look like this:

```
var httpError = new HttpError(exception, true);
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in exception.Data)
{
    httpError.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value);
}
var httpResponseMessage =
  Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, httpError);
```